# CRM 2011 List Component Error - The document records could not be loaded.

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I've recently installed the "CRM List Component" on a "Online SharePoint", but there are some problems when documents are added.

I'm getting "**The document records could not be loaded from SharePoint. Try refreshing the grid. If the problem persists, contact your system administrator**" error when adding any kind of document.

When I restart the page, the "CRM List Component" view isn't shown anymore and I see the complete SharePoint instead of the normal "View".

I've downloaded the latest "CRM List Component" on the Microsoft Site and even tried to add a new "site Library" (contact2) and it doesn't work on other "Site Libraries" too.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

If so, is there a way to resolve this?

The weird thing is, that I've done this for other customers and there it seemed to work correctly.

But I can't delete an "Online SharePoint" environment and start from scratch as it is a new environment created by the  customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I’ve solved the Issue Myself after some research.  The language of the User who created the SharePoint was different from my “SharePoint”-user.  When I changed the language of my User, the problem seems to be disappeared.  I guess this issue won’t be solved in the next releases of the “CRM List Component”? I’m hoping that this answer will help out other Users!

Comment: Thanks—that worked for me! Absurd that this feature doesn't work properly in a multi-lingual environment.

Answer (score 1):

It is not always feasible to keep user's language same as site collection language. There can be a requirement to have alternative languages enabled on the site collection, where integration component is deployed. Instead of enforcing site collection language you can set the integration component language to be always same, regardless of the user language settings.  This can be done by adding for example *UICulture="en" Culture="en-US"* attribute to the Page directive of the affected page **CrmGridPage.aspx**.

You can access CrmGridPage.aspx by unpacking the component's .wsp file as CAB archive. Then edit the page, archive back into CAB, rename into wsp and deploy.